# WSO2 API Manager : change cache lib

Tags: caching, wso2, wso2-api-manager, ignite

I am using the APIM 1.10.0 version.

The following are described in the WSO2 Document. (https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB490/About+this+Release)

[image]

I have questions that are listed below.

1. Does the document mean that APIM 1.10.0 version use hazelcast for storing response?
2. If i want use ehcache, just add the ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3.jar to the /repository/components/libs directory?
3. How to verify that ehcache is operating properly?
4. To use the apache ignite for storing response that will create the same 
   structure as the ehcache_1.5.0.wso2v3.jar?
5. Do you provide a jar or bundle to use apache ignite?